# Trilogy spanning past, present and future

Tags: story-identification, novel, soft-sci-fi

I am looking to identify a book trilogy I read. I am pretty sure I read it in the early 2000s, but I don't know when it was written. If I had to guess, I would say it was likely pretty new when I read it (possibly written in the late 90s). I thought it was a Twilight Zone story but I haven't been able to find any of those that match my memory so it is possible I am mistaken on that point.

Each book in the trilogy covered a different time period. One was the past (about medieval times) , one the approximate present and one in the future.

I believe there was at least one character who is involved in all three books (Let's call him John since I can't remember his name and having a name makes this description easier to read). I know that in the future book he is disembodied and he possesses a woman (Let's call her Jane). Many people in that time have phones implanted in their jaws so Jane is able to talk to John without people thinking she is crazy.

I think John may have been alive in the past story, but I don't remember for sure.

I think that in the future story, someone is planning to force another disembodied soul into an unwilling person's body. I think John and Jane work together to try to stop this.

The trilogy may have used the theme about magic really being science sufficiently advanced so as not to be understood. I.e. There may have been "magic" in the past book but the same things were seen as science in the future book.

So the parts that I remember clearly are that it was a trilogy with each book set in a different era and in the future a disembodied spirit possesses a woman and they work together. Also, in the future many people have phones embedded in their jaws.

I have tried these Google searches:

1. scifi book trilogy past present future - unfortunately I am not looking for Frank Sinatra's album "Trilogy: Past Present and Future"
2. scifi book phone embedded in jaw - Results show Warship, Red Moon, The Circle Trilogy, Harper Hall Trilogy, The Sentinel, etc. I haven't yet seen any that match what I remember.

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have a good start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/62201) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.

Comment: How far in the past are we talking for the first book?

Comment: @Broklynite it was medieval-ish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems I didn't give the *Twilight Zone* angle a fair shake. The books I was trying to find are:

1. *Shades of Night, Falling* (Sometimes called *Harvest Moon*) by John J. Miller (Published 2003)
2. *A Gathering of Shadows* by Russell Davis (Published 2003)
3. *Deep in the Dark* by John Hellers (Published 2004)

They are part of a *Twilight Zone* trilogy. There seems to be very little information about them online which might be why I had a such a hard time finding them. Since asking the question, I have found and read all three books.

The trilogy follows two families: the Noirs and the Derlichts in a small town, Geistadt, outside Brooklyn.

Book one is set in 1842 (So not medieval as I had thought). Benjamin Noir has traveled the world to learn the secrets of using magic. He wants thirteen sons for some magical reason. Twins Thomas and Jonathan are his thirteenth and fourteenth sons, respectively by birth. Benjamin gives Thomas everything he wants and trains him in using magic and essentially ignores Jonathan. 1842 is the year of the twins' 21st birthday. The matriarch of the Derlicht family at this time is Agatha. The Noirs and the Derlichts have been feuding since Benjamin moved to Geistadt.

Murders begin occurring once per day in Geistadt and the town attempts to discover the culprit.

Book two is set in 2002. Thomas' great-grandson Mason, the thirteenth son of his father (who is also a thirteenth son) is working on a way to download human consciousness from the body. He calls this invention MindNet. Thomas' spirit visits Mason in dream-like encounters. Mason eventually realizes that Thomas wants to use MindNet to retake a human form.

Antonia Derlicht is the thirteenth daughter of Agatha's great-great-grandson. She is doing a project for her graduate degree in Literature. Her project revolves around the ghost stories of Geistadt. To help in her research, her father shows her the historical records kept by the Derlicht family. As Antonia reads the records, she begins to interact with the spirit of Agatha. Antonia's father also encourages her to meet-and hopefully marry-Mason.

Book three is set in 2159. Mason has perfected MindNet and human cloning meaning that he can move to a new, healthy body when needed. Essentially he has allowed those that can afford it to be immortal. His next goal is to revive Benjamin from some of his blood that was preserved in a conopic jar while Benjamin was alive. While attempting the resurrection, reality seems to unravel. Strange things start happening like buildings disappearing, adults reverting to infancy and trees appearing on the side of skyscrapers.

Shuzumi Mader (called Jane in the question) is a police cadet at the time and a Noir descendant. She has a phone implanted in her jaw. Jonathan's spirit (called John in the question) reaches out to her and asks for her help in stopping the craziness. She finds where his spirit is trapped and he enters her body where she can talk to him. He directs her to a Derlicht descendant, Ryan, and together they head to the building where Mason is attempting to revive Benjamin.